# Create a cascading md-select / md-options dropdown in Angular.js (Dynamic JSON's)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I've two JSON's files.

The first file is a list of all countries.

```
{
 "gid"=1,
 "name"="Afghanisthan",
 "parentId"=null
}
...and so on!
```

The second file is a list of all timezones.

```
{
 "gid"=1,
 "name"="UTC -12:00",
 "parentId=null
}
```

The timezones are related in database to id of list the countries, through a stored procedure.

They've load data perfectly in the view.

My controller:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.test_angular_node')
    .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', testCtrl]);

    function testCtrl($scope, $http) {

      //Combo de países
      $scope.comboCountries = null;

      $scope.comboTimezones = null;

      $scope.countries = [];

      $scope.timeZones = [];


      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'db/comboCountry'
      }).success(function(data){

        $scope.countries = data;


      }).error(function(error){
        console.log('Error en carga de datos de DB', error);
      });

      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'db/comboTime'
      }).success(function(data){

        $scope.timeZones = data;

      }).error(function(error){
        console.log('Error en carga de datos de DB', error);
      });

    }

})();
```

My view:

```html
<div class="page" ng-controller="testCtrl">

    <div class="row ui-section">
        <div class="col-lg-8 clearfix">
            <h2 class="section-header">TEST</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <md-select ng-name="comboCountries" ng-model="comboCountries">
              <md-option data-ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.gid}}">
                  {{country.name}}
              </md-option>
          </md-select>
          <md-select ng-name="comboTimezones" ng-model="comboTimezones">
              <md-option data-ng-repeat="timeZone in timeZones">
                  {{timeZone.name}}
              </md-option>
          </md-select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need:

How I could filtering the data, that the second dropdown loads only the timezones related to `country.gid` of countries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

We are going to just use the ng-change method. Try this in the controller. I have added my own dummy data:

```
$scope.comboCountries = null;
  $scope.comboTimezones = null;
  $scope.countries = [
  {
   "gid":1,
   "name":"Afghanisthan",
   "parentId":"1"
  },{
   "gid":1,
   "name":"Another Country",
   "parentId":"2"
  },{
   "gid":1,
   "name":"The Last Country",
   "parentId":"3"
  }];
  $scope.timeZones = [
  {
 "gid":1,
 "name":"Afghanisthan - UTC -12:00",
 "parentId":"1"
  },
  {
 "gid":1,
 "name":"Afghanisthan - UTC -12:00",
 "parentId":"1"
  },
  {
 "gid":1,
 "name":"Another Country - UTC -12:00",
 "parentId":"2"
  },
  {
 "gid":1,
 "name":"Another Country - UTC -12:00",
 "parentId":"2"
  },
  {
 "gid":1,
 "name":"The Last Country - UTC -12:00",
 "parentId":"3"
  },
  {
 "gid":1,
 "name":"The Last Country - UTC -12:00",
 "parentId":"3"
  } 
  ];

  function checkTimeZone(timeZone) {
      return timeZone.parentId ==  $scope.comboCountries;
  }

  $scope.getTimeZones = function(comboCountries){
  $scope.timeZones = $scope.timeZones.filter(checkTimeZone);
  }
```

Now let's get to the view (HTML)..

```
<div class="row ui-section">
        <div class="col-lg-8 clearfix">
            <h2 class="section-header"></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <select ng-model="comboCountries" ng-change="getTimeZones(comboCountries)">
              <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.parentId}}">
                  {{country.name}}
              </option>
          </select>
          <select ng-name="comboTimezones" ng-model="comboTimezones">
              <option ng-repeat="timeZone in timeZones">
                  {{timeZone.name}}
              </option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**OLD ANSWER**
You can try this if you want to use a filter, you could also just do it in the controller. (i.e. just "filter" your timeZones in the controller using an ng-change on your comboCountries select.)

```
<select
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="comboCountries"
    ng-options="country in countries">
</select>

<select
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="comboTimezones"
    ng-options="timeZone in timeZones | filter:{parentId: comboCountries.parentId}">
</select>
```

Comment: That's not work for me, because I've a store procedure that relates the JSON countries with JSON timezones... I've created functions in Node.js for this, but I don't know how populate these functions from Angular.js

Comment: are you saying you need to make a new call to the rest services once you get the comboCountries parent id?

Comment: Yes, is there a function that throws the second JSON list (timezones), even that receives as parameter the gid from JSON countries list (the parentId).

Comment: I've let an empty array, and therefore loads all timezones.

Comment: hold on, let me make sure I am on the same page. Do you need to send the parameter parent id to  url: 'db/comboTime'? If so, we can do the ng-change?

Comment: actually can you just create a quick plunkr? this is a quick problem I could solve if I could make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124548/discussion-between-defaultcheckbox-and-ulises-vargas-de-sousa).